# How would one animate UILabel text property with CoreAnimation in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, uiviewanimation, cabasicanimation

I want to increment UILabel.text value from 0 to say 100 using CoreAnimation with easing functions (e.g. easeInOutQuad). But it seems like text property is not animatable. So how to achieve this with the help of CA? Or Would I need to implement easing function myself and call it using GCD?
Thanks

P.S. I'd like to stick to CA as much as possible.

Comment: Is it fair to say that you have a numerical property that you want to animate and that its value is shown in a label, and that for each frame of the animation you want the label to display the (formatted) interpolated numerical value?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I want to achieve.

Comment: @David Rönnqvist I tried to animate custom property with didSet observer where I update UILabel value, but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    var counter = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("animate"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        timer.fire()
    }

    func animate() {
        UIView.transitionWithView(label,
                              duration: 1.0,
                              options: [.CurveEaseInOut],
                              animations: { () -> Void in
                                self.counter += 1
                                self.label.text = "\(self.counter)"
        }, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Comment: Probably I didn't make myself clear. I want value to animate incrementally during animation time: 1..2..3..4...100

Comment: Try setting a country property, and setup a NSTimer (scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:) which calls a method with the above code, but instead of Hello World set it to the value of the property.

Comment: Thank you Jasper, but this way I don't see intermediate values (incrementing numbers).

Comment: mra214, I have edited my post. Please let me know if this works out. It works for me but I am not 100% sure I understand your problem :)

Comment: Yes, Jasper, it did work, although not exactly what I want. In your example easing function applied only to adjacent values, but I need it to be applied to the whole animation, but I think I can solve it. So I accept your answer. (for now :)). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, hope you can work it out yourself. Perhaps try doing it the other way around. Add one animation and try and do the counting within it. I am not sure but maybe the timer can run within the animation closure?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that using core animation. You can add animation to your label. Try out following

```
CATransition *textAnimation = [CATransition animation];
textAnimation.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
textAnimation.duration = 0.5;
textAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
[numLabel.layer addAnimation:textAnimation forKey:@"changeTextTransition"];
```

You can change your label text anytime later on adding animation and it will animate.

```
numLabel.text = "1";
```